# Converting letters to numbers in C++

Tags: c++

PROBLEM SOLVED: thanks everyone!

I am almost entirely new to C++ so I apologise in advance if the question seems trivial.

I am trying to convert a string of letters to a set of 2 digit numbers where a = 10, b = 11, ..., Y = 34, Z = 35 so that (for example) "abc def" goes to "101112131415". How would I go about doing this? Any help would really be appreciated. Also, I don't mind whether capitalization results in the same number or a different number. Thank you very much in advance. I probably won't need it for a few days but if anyone is feeling particularly nice how would I go about reversing this process? i.e. "101112131415" --> "abcdef" Thanks.

EDIT: This isn't homework, I'm entirely self taught. I have completed this project before in a different language and decided to try C++ to compare the differences and try to learn C++ in the process :)

EDIT: I have roughly what I want, I just need a little bit of help converting this so that it applies to strings, thanks guys.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int returnVal (char x)
{
    return (int) x - 87;
}

int main()
{
    char x = 'g';
    std::cout << returnVal(x);
}
```

Comment: A first step might be to look at the value of `'z' - 'a'`.

Comment: "123" = 1*100 + 2*10 + 3*1

Comment: Another interesting question will be the result of `'a'-'A'`

Comment: You only need `10+str[i]-'a'`.

Comment: Why not should us you code to date

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to redo a project in a language that's new to me which is why the question seems so trivial. It's not homework.

Comment: Note a character is already an integer. The issue is that the `std::cout` is overloaded to print out the character representation rather than the integer representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each character has it's ASCII values. Try converting your characters into ASCII and then manipulate the difference.

Example:

```
int x = 'a';
cout << x;
```

will print 97; and

```
int x = 'a';
cout << x - 87;
```

will print 10.

Hence, you could write a function like this:

```
int returnVal(char x)
{
    return (int)x - 87;
}
```

to get the required output.

And your main program could look like:

```
int main()
{
    string s = "abcdef"
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << returnVal(s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A portable method is to use a table lookup:

```
const unsigned int letter_to_value[] = 
{10, 11, 12, /*...*/, 35};

// ...

letter = toupper(letter);
const unsigned int index = letter - 'A';
value = letter_to_value[index];
cout << index;
```

Answer (score 1):

Many answers will tell you that characters are encoded in ASCII and that you can convert a letter to an index by subtracting `'a'`.

This is not proper C++. It is acceptable when your program requirements include a specification that ASCII is in use. However, the C++ standard alone does not require this. There are C++ implementations with other character sets.

In the absence of knowledge that ASCII is in use, you can use translation tables:

```
#include <limits.h>

// Define a table to translate from characters to desired codes:
static unsigned int Translate[UCHAR_MAX] =
{
    ['a'] = 10,
    ['b'] = 11,
    …
};
```

Then you may translate characters to numbers by looking them up in the table:

```
unsigned char x = something;

int result = Translate[x];
```

Once you have the translation, you could print it as two digits using `printf("%02d", result);`.

Translating in the other direction requires reading two characters, converting them to a number (interpreting them as decimal), and performing a similar translation. You might have a different translation table set up for this reverse translation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do it, if not messy.

```
map<char, int> vals; // maps a character to an integer

int g = 1; // if a needs to be 10 then set g = 10

string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for(char c : alphabet) { // kooky krazy for loop
    vals[c] = g;
    g++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Daniel said, try it out for yourself.

As a starting point though, casting:

```
int i = (int)string[0] + offset;
```

will get you your number from character, and: `stringstream` will be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about doing this?

By trying to do **something** first, and looking for help only if you feel you cannot advance.

That being said, the most obvious solution that comes to mind is based on the fact that characters (i.e. `'a'`, `'G'`) are really numbers. Suppose you have the following:

```
char c = 'a';
```

You can get the number associated with `c` by doing:

```
int n = static_cast<int>(c);
```

Then, add some offset to 'n':

```
n += 10;
```

...and cast it back to a `char`:

```
c = static_cast<char>(n);
```

Note: The above assumes that characters are consecutive, i.e. the number corresponding to `'a'` is equal to the one corresponding to `'z'` minus the amount of letters between the two. This usually holds, though.

Answer (score 0):

This can work

`int Number = 123;       // number to be converted to a string`

`string Result;          // string which will contain the result`

`ostringstream convert;   // stream used for the conversion`

`convert << Number;      // insert the textual representation of 'Number' in the characters in the stream`

`Result = convert.str(); // set 'Result' to the contents of the stream`

you should add this headers
`#include <sstream>`
`#include <string>`

Answer (score 0):

Just do this !

```
(s[i] - 'A' + 1)
```

Basically we are converting a char to number by subtracting it by A and then adding 1 to match the number and letters

Comment: When answering on stackoverflow, please don't just correct the code/suggest the answer. Please also explain why this is answer works, so the OP can learn from it.

Comment: @JVApen Surely I will do that